# Opencv 3.3.0 on python 3.6.3 crash on imshow

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I've just started playing around with opencv 3.3.0 with python 3.6.3 and this problem occurred with the first thing I've tried.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After running this, an window for an image opens and then I get a Windows' popup error "Python has stopped working". Otherwise python works properly, just as well as opencv for as much as I could notice.

Comment: without imshow, does it crash? how did you install OpenCV? have you tried the latest version?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @api55 Without imshow it does not crash and opencv I've installed through 'pip install opencv-python'. I assume it's the lates compatible version.

Comment: @Miki error is just generic windows window popup saying "Python has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..."

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the right module or have you tried updating it? I found a 3.3.1 version on https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv
opencv_python‑3.3.1+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl.

Comment: I have 3.3.0 installed.That's the one that came up with 'pip install opencv-python'.